# Are there any practical uses of allowing recursive inclusion of a file?

Tags: language-agnostic, compiler

I am currently implementing NASM-like preprocessor for my assembler, and I am wondering what is the correct way of handling recursively included files. From what I see, there are two ways to deal with it without hanging the preprocessor or even the OS:

1. Set maximum include depth.
2. Disallow including a file recursively (not to be confused with disallowing including a file *twice*).

Also, as far as I can see, the second approach does essentially the same job, but produces nicer error messages. Compare output of Clang, when compiling file containing `#include "main.cpp"` only:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
[ repeated many times ]
In file included from main.cpp:1:
main.cpp:1:10: error: #include nested too deeply
#include "main.cpp"
```

with this (current way of handling this in my preprocessor; input is similar to above, does `%include "1.mov.asm"` at line 6):

```
In file /home/griwes/projects/reaverasm/tests/1.mov.asm in line 6:
Error: file `/home/griwes/projects/reaverasm/tests/1.mov.asm` included recursively.
```

The approach disallowing recursive inclusion produces - IMHO - more readable output.

The question is: **is there any preprocessor technique that would be killed by disallowing recursive inclusion?** This question is language-agnostic, so feel free to give examples from any languages.

Comment: Nice question. I immediately fired up my IDE (Delphi2007) to see what that does. It detects the recursion on compile (error) but it still hangs if I open one of the recurring files (takes full CPU on one core) with memory increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Boost.Preprocessor library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) extends and abuses the C/C++ preprocessor in strange and wonderful ways.  One of its features is [file iteration](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/file_iteration.html), which lets you #include a file multiple times with different macros #define'd each time, and they note that it can be useful (and is supported) for a file to iterate over itself.  (Search [the examples here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/file_iteration.html) for `BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING`.)  This is an example of (limited) recursion.

Comment: Oh heck. "Boost.PP [...] abuses" is exactly the way one should call that...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're conflating two different things:

1. Whether to allow recursive inclusion
2. The error output

I have seen multiple real-world examples where recursive inclusion was desired, but it was usually to work around limitations in the preprocessor. I feel it is wrong to disallow any recursion but a limit of 10 times is reasonable IMO.

Comment: Well, those two things are quite close to each other; depending on how you handle the recursive inclusion, you either get one error output or another. Also, could you provide some of those examples when recursive inclusion was desired?